# Armazenamento Android

Tags: java, android, session, cache, armazenamento

estou iniciando no universo de Android, e tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Em um sistema de login, qual tipo armazenamento eu deveria utilizar para persistir os dados do usuário que efetuou o login naquela sessão,
e quando eu clicar em sair "matar" essas informações da sessão?

Comment: você pode utilizar o  SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas formas de persistência em Android. Você pode utilizar desde APIs prontas de autenticação (como a do Facebook e Google), ou banco de dados simples como o SQLite do próprio Android ou até mesmo o SharedPreferences.

Um exemplo seria, você autenticar e salvar os dados no SharedPrefences e quando o usuário sair você limpa o preferences.

Nesse exemplo abaixo eu persisti os dados do login no preferences (que fica no app) e quando o usuário abre o app de novo eu verifico se ele já fez o login alguma vez na vida e se ele fez, ele não precisa realizar novamente.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(Contract.SETTINGS_PREF, 0);
    String name = preferences.getString(Contract.USER_NAME_PREF, "");
    String email = preferences.getString(Contract.USER_EMAIL_PREF, "");
    String password = preferences.getString(Contract.USER_PASSWORD_PREF, "");

    if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
        logIn(email, password);
    }

    binding.txtCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateAccountActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa opção é vc utilizar algum web service para fazer o login e armazenar seus dados e utilizar o sqlLite como se fosse um "super cache". 
Da uma olhada no firebase, ele tem ótimas formas de autenticação: por email ou rede social. Além disso vc pode salvar seus dados e arquivos.
https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br